# LWUIT J2ME Display.init(his) Error

Tags: java, exception, lwuit

I'm trying to play with LWUIT and siMple app like "hello world"..
But first line in `StartApp()` - `Display.init(this)` - causes app to close throwing uncaught exception..
I'm totally confused..

```
import com.sun.lwuit.Command;
import com.sun.lwuit.Container;
import com.sun.lwuit.Dialog;
import com.sun.lwuit.Display;
import com.sun.lwuit.Form;
import com.sun.lwuit.TextArea;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionEvent;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionListener;
import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.BorderLayout;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;

public class Main extends MIDlet {

    private int selectedIndex;
    private Form f;

    public Main() {}

public void startApp()  {
    System.out.println("before");
    try {
        System.out.println("during");
        Display.init(this);
    } catch(Exception h) {
        System.out.println("after");
        h.printStackTrace();
    }
}
  protected void destroyApp(boolean arg0) throws MIDletStateChangeException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
  protected void pauseApp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: could you please share the error log?

Comment: There's no error log.... App doesn't even open ...

Comment: i mean there must be something in the error window. What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on your imports. I think that the problem is there. I will remove the javax.microedition.lcdui.*;

Here in this web, you can see, how the Nokia UI Demo starts.

[Nokia UI DEMO MIDlet](https://projects.developer.nokia.com/LWUIT_for_Series_40/browser/lwuit_for_series_40/Apps/LWUITDemo/src/com/sun/lwuit/uidemo/Main.java)

**Another solution that I find looking on my code. Put the `Display.init(this)`in the Midlet constructor instead in the startApp method.**

Answer (score 0):

Before any Form is shown the Developer must invoke Display.init(Object m) in order to register the current MIDlet.